# ref.current.focus() does not open keyboard, but works once the browser app is reopened

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React.js project and I want users to be able to use the keyboard to type some text in `contentEditable={true}`  right after they open the page.

So I used `useRef()` and `ref.current.focus()` to do so. It works fine on PC, but not on mobile.

Some strange behaviors I noticed are

- `document.activeElement` seems to be different on PC and mobile hmm
- As described earlier, I do not see caret with `ref.current.focus()` and keyboard does not pop up right away. However, if I close the browser on my phone and reopen it, keyboard pops up and the focus is on the element I referenced to, and see the caret.

It happens on both Safari and Chrome browsers.

If anybody has seen anything like this, please share some ideas! Thanks! Happy Coding!

P.S. Here is the [codepen link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cache-7ybu69?file=/src/App.js)